# Do I use the simple tense or continuous in this case?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, present-continuous, present-simple

It's full day and I'm interacting with a co-worker:

> Don't mind if I **yawn** a lot while you're talking. I **didn't sleep** /
> **haven't slept** all night.
>
> Don't mind if I'm **yawning** a lot while you're talking. I **didn't sleep** /
> **haven't slept** all night.

What is the correct option?

Comment: "I didn't **sleep at all/get any sleep** last night"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"didn't sleep" is correct. "haven't slept" suggests that the night is still going on, and you are still trying to go to sleep. It's what you'd say to your partner who complains that you are still rolling around trying to get comfortable at 4 in the morning.

"I yawn" or "I'm yawning" is too close to call. I would use the first, as it sounds more correct to my native English mind.

However, I would be tempted to add "Please" in front of the question in order to make it a polite apology.

In fact, I would probably say: "Please don't mind **me yawning** a lot ..."

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Don't mind if I yawn a lot while you're talking.
>    I didn't sleep / haven't slept all night.
> 2. Don't mind if I'm yawning a lot while you're talking.
>
>    I didn't sleep / haven't slept all night.

Answer **1** is correct. If it is still night, then say *haven't slept all night.*
If it is the next day, then say *I didn't sleep*.